# How to send email using pyrocms?

Tags: pyrocms

When i am trying to send email using pyrocms it shows email_template table doesn't exists but this table is exists in database with default_email_template name.I have changed name of that table but error is not solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to send e-mails in pyrocms is by using `Events::trigger('email', $data, 'array')`

The $data array is the data you're using in the email template, while the third parameter is "the type of response you expect" (see [pyrocms docs](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers/tools/events#contact-triggers)).

The $data array should at least include the "slug" key - this the slug of the e-mail template you want to be sent.

The $data array can also include "from", "name", "reply-to", "to" and "lang". If those are not provided, pyrocms uses the corresponding settings of your website (you can change them in the settings part of the backend)

Comment: please accept the answer, so other users can see that this helped to solve the problem.

Comment: @mgrueter There's a small base of community for PyroCMS though this is a great CMS/CMF. Could you tell us how you identified the fields available for ``$data``? It's just that it's not in docs. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: Sure. The event is defined in `system/cms/modules/templates/events.php`. I was just going through the code (its not much), and noted which parameters are getting used in the actual send_email function. Most important is the `slug` (which is the slug of the email template that should be used). Other parameters are `lang`, `from`, `name`, `reply-to`, `to` and `attach`. If those parameters aren't included, they will be substituted with the corresponding value of your installation - e. g. `server_mail` (taken from the settings) as from address.